# Core Data issue

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I implemented core data in my app.

I am fetching data in `ViewWillAppear` method.

I am assign fetch result to local array.

Now, I make change on `TextFiledDidEndEditing` method to local array, but not saved to persistence store.

But when I again come to that view & try to re-fretch on `ViewWillAppear` method then that changed remain as it is.

**Help to solve this**

**Thank you**

Comment: Please add your source code

Comment: @User, it is complex code 
So I just told the flow of the scenario. "Code is not always needed"

Comment: Where are you saving the array? Is it in the same view controller you are opening and closing?

Comment: What is the error while saving in `textFiledDidEndEditing` ? What is code for saving it?

Comment: I just only change value of field by KVO 
but not saving to persistence Store.

Comment: It sounds like you aren't saving the array. You're just changing it, but when you run the view controller again, it resets to the old array.

Comment: @User, it is not resetting that is the problem. please check question.

Answer (score 0):

`NSFetchRequest` has a property `includesPendingChanges`, which has a default of `true`. Just bear this in mind.

`NSManagedObjectContext` can tell you about `insertedObjects`, `updatedObjects` and `deletedObjects`.

The above all relates to dirty context state - changes you've made but which haven't been saved yet.

So while you aren't saving your change the context is still dirty with the change and each time you make a request the managed objects you get back will have those changes. The only thing you can filter out is inserted or deleted objects by using the fetch request flag (though that isn't your case here).

If you want to get rid of the changes you should use an undo manager, so `rollback` or `reset` the context.

Comment: you still haven't 100% explained what the problem is or shown any code so it's impossible for me to say anything other than the above.

Comment: array value is not reset while re-fetching.

Comment: I added core-data objects into an array. after that I changed array's object by KVO but not stored in persistence . when I try to re-fetch objects from DB then it shows me result arrays with changed value.

Comment: so when did you call reset and how didn't it work. rollback would't work if you don't have an undo manager

Comment: rollback works for previous transaction but not for latest one
so last transaction is not reset